# A simple substitution cipher in Python 2

Tags: python, encryption

The code below shifts each letter of the plaintext message 2 positions in the alphabet.  The problem is this code doesn't loop back to beginning of the alphabet after the letters y and z or Y and Z. I've been trying to fix this for a bit now. What can I do to fix this?

```
msg = raw_input("any string goes here")

cypher = ""

for a in msg:

     cypher = cypher + chr(ord(a) + 2)

print cypher
```

Comment: Hint: look into the modulo operator.

Answer (score 3):

You could make your own list of an ascii alphabet using the the `string` module. Then you wouldn't have to worry about all of the other unicode characters involved with the `ord` method. An example for lowercase ascii letters would be:

```
import string
msg = raw_input("any string goes here")

cypher = ""
#creates a alphabet of lowercase ascii characters
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

for a in msg:

    cypher = cypher + alphabet[((alphabet.index(a) + 2) % 26)]

print cypher
```

Or if you were really set on using the `ord` method you could use this:

```
 cypher = cypher + chr(((ord(a) - 95) % 26) + 97)
```

To explain this a little better, in unicode the alphabet starts at index 97 (97 = "a") and ending index of 122 (122 = "z"). So by subtracting 95, I am effectively increasing the letter index by two. Then to take care of the wrapping to the beginning problem we use 
`% 26` so that the index is always between 0 and 25. Then finally I added 97 so that the index is back in the 97 to 122 range of the alphabet for unicode.

Answer (score 0):

```
cypher = cypher + chr((ord(a) + 2) % 26)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into the modulo operator.

It could be something like:
    cypher + chr((ord(a) + 2) % 26